# ffmpeg and ffmpeg-php install on fedora 13

Tags: ffmpeg

i want to install FFMPEG and ffmpeg-php in my FC13 machine.I have tried a lot of blogs but i got error while installing ffmpeg-php.Let me know any good blogs or install prodecures.Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Companion.

Answer (score 5):

It is in rpmfusion, as are many of the extras needed for Fedora.

```
su
rpm -Uvh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-stable.noarch.rpm
yum -y install ffmpeg
```